# Is there a way I can read a xml file in java without having to define the class to read into

Tags: java, xml

I am experimenting with JAXB library to read xml files and I see that I need to define the Class objects along with annotations to indicate the xml element structure. I was wondering if there is a way that I can read the xml file without having to define such a class. this will permit the user to add a new tag without having to redefine my class.

I am not particular about jaxb usage, any other java libraries are ok too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, if you just want to work with raw XML without binding it onto POJOs, you can use `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`/`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` to read any arbitrary XML directly into a [org.w3c.dom.Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) and just work with it as a document instead of as mapped data.

Comment: Thanks! We load the document and read each element using getChildElement etc apis.